# How to test for sig. differences between variance components of random effects?

Tags: r, variance, random-effects-model

The aim is to determine at which level to group data (i. e. at individual, plot or regional level) by comparing the variance components in a random effects model.

```
mod <- lmer(val ~ (1|individual) + (1|plot) + (1|region))
confint(mod)
                2.5 %    97.5 %
.sig01      0.2514234 0.2826764
.sig02      0.2443112 0.3292156
.sig03      0.1548823 0.3659306
.sigma      0.8462618 0.8548915
(Intercept) 1.1728222 1.4402827
```

How should the variance components be compared so as to decide which level(s) of aggregation to retain in subsequent models?

Comment: is this helpful? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56150/how-can-i-test-whether-a-random-effect-is-significant

Comment: @rep_ho Unfortunately not. I'd like to compare different random effects that all have a variance > 0.

Comment: But if they have ale variance >0 then you should keep them all no?

Comment: One way might be to compare models with and without each random effect via model fit.

Comment: @Sointu that is the same as testing if the effect is signification which is discussed in the link I shared

Comment: Ah, yeah sorry. I don't know a formal way of testing whether one random effect is larger than another. Maybe just using the confidence intervals would be the way - in that case your three random effects would not significantly differ from each other as the CIs are overlapping. But if the (ultimate) goal is to figure out which random effects to include into a model, I do think you should include all three as they all clearly have cluster-specific variance re: your outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that this part of the model development process, then I would recommend choosing the grouping variable based on the one with the lowest AIC (similar to what you would do in a stepwise AIC process).

```
require(lme4)

dataf <- data.frame(
   individual = factor(rep(1:100, times = 2)),
   plot = factor(rep(1:10, 20)),
   region = factor(rep(1:4, 50))
 )
 
# make the true dependence on the plot grouping
set.seed(1933)
dataf$val <- 7 + as.numeric(dataf$plot)/10 + rnorm(200, 0, 1)
 
mod_i <- lme4::lmer(val ~ (1|individual), data = dataf)
mod_p <- lme4::lmer(val ~ (1|plot), data = dataf)
mod_r <- lme4::lmer(val ~ (1|region), data = dataf)
boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')
 
> extractAIC(mod_i)
[1]   3.000 617.753
> extractAIC(mod_p)
[1]   3.0000 608.7551
> extractAIC(mod_r)
[1]   3.0000 621.5314
 
mod_pi <- lme4::lmer(val ~ (1|plot) + (1|individual), data = dataf)
mod_pr <- lme4::lmer(val ~ (1|plot) + (1|region), data = dataf)
 
> extractAIC(mod_pi)
[1]   4.0000 610.0804
> extractAIC(mod_pr)
[1]   4.0000 610.7551
 
# Final model is mod_p with the lowest AIC
 
 
 
# make the true dependence on the individual grouping
set.seed(1933)
dataf$val <- 7 + as.numeric(dataf$individual)/100 + rnorm(200, 0, 1)
 
mod_i <- lme4::lmer(val ~ (1|individual), data = dataf)
mod_p <- lme4::lmer(val ~ (1|plot), data = dataf)
mod_r <- lme4::lmer(val ~ (1|region), data = dataf)
 
> extractAIC(mod_i)
[1]   3.000 603.226
> extractAIC(mod_p)
[1]   3.0000 604.1367
> extractAIC(mod_r)
[1]   3.0000 604.7195
 
mod_ip <- lme4::lmer(val ~ (1|individual) + (1|plot), data = dataf)
mod_ir <- lme4::lmer(val ~ (1|individual) + (1|region), data = dataf)
 
> extractAIC(mod_ip)
[1]   4.0000 604.9881
> extractAIC(mod_ir)
[1]   4.000 605.226
 
# final model is mod_i with the lowest AIC
```

If the ultimate question is testing whether the grouping variable is statistically significant in the final model, then I also recommend the [posting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56150/how-can-i-test-whether-a-random-effect-is-significant) in the comment that @rep_ho made on the original question. Specifically, take a look at the `RLRsim` package.